# Cakephp 3.0 Unique Email

Tags: cakephp, unique, cakephp-3.0

im quite new to cakephp, i need help with setting up unique email and the error message. This is how my model looks like. Thank you!

```
 <?php
 namespace App\Model\Table;

 use Cake\ORM\Table;
 use Cake\Validation\Validator;

  class UsersTable extends Table
  {

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    return $validator
        ->notEmpty('email', 'A email is required')
        ->add('email', 'valid' , ['rule'=> 'email'])
        ->requirePresence('email','create')

        ->notEmpty('password', 'A password is required')
        ->notEmpty('role', 'A role is required')
        ->add('role', 'inList', [
            'rule' => ['inList', ['admin', 'author']],
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid role'
        ]);
}

}
```

Comment: Please add more informations about the problem you're having. You might want to have a look at our [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), and in particular to the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: Just add a [unique](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#unique-fields) rule?

Comment: Thank you! i added ->add('email', [
    'unique' => ['rule' => 'validateUnique', 'provider' => 'table']
]);        And it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other way would be to add it to the buildRules() function of your Table Model.

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
    return $rules;
}
```